# Unreal Engine 4: Delegates vs Iteration for multiple instances

Tags: delegates, iteration, instance, unreal-engine4

## PseudoCode

Cube { Speed x; }

CubeContainer { Cube[] Cubes }

## Question

Say I want to update the speed of **all** my instanced Cubes in a level, is it more efficient to give the cubes delegate methods that are called when necessary or iterate over the array of cubes and call a setter method?

Comment: I would cache and iterate them, it will faster but only slightly as a multicast delegate will also ultimately just iterate an array, only with a few extra checks and whistles.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!